# SQL: Combining sum and max aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get the max value from the following query:

```
select sum(hours) from works_on group by pno;   
+------------+
| sum(hours) |
+------------+
|      52.50 |
|      50.00 |
|      55.00 |
|      25.00 |
|      55.00 |
+------------+
```

What I want is:

```
|      55.00 |
|      55.00 |
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Having` Clause and `Sub-query`. Something like this

```
SELECT Sum(hours) 
FROM   works_on 
GROUP  BY pno 
HAVING Sum(hours) = (SELECT Sum(hours) h 
                     FROM   works_on 
                     GROUP  BY pno 
                     ORDER  BY h DESC 
                     LIMIT  1)
```

But it is really easy in `SQL SERVER` where we have `TOP 1 with Ties` which avoids the `sub-query`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the maximum value, then one row will do:

```
select sum(hours)
from works_on
group by pno
order by sum(hours) desc
limit 1;
```

I'm not certain why you would want two rows, but then Prdp's answer is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

or, another approach that just returns the max sum, (one row only)
 is

```
Select Max(sumHrs)
From (Select sum(hours) sumHrs
      From works_on 
      gtoup by pno) z
```

I wonder, what is the value of returning multiple rows from a resultset that is already an aggregation, and not the raw data rows. If your desired results also included the `pno` value, then I would understand (you want to know which `pno`s have the highest sum of hours), but to just get the max sum of hours doesn't seem to have much value.  Or did you just leave part of the probl;em out for simplicity?

Comment: For this we can use `Order By` with `Limit` to get the Max value.